# How to prove that Weyl tensor is invariant under conformal transformations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature, metric-tensor

I need to verify that the solution for vanishing [Weyl tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_tensor) is conformally flat metric $g_{\mu\nu} = e^{2\varphi}\eta_{\mu\nu}$. The most convenient way to show this is to prove that Weyl tensor is invariant under conformal transformation of the metric. How to prove this fast?

I have the idea to build 4-rank tensor which include terms with curvature tensor, Ricci tensor and scalar curvature and then use the requirement on invariance under infinitesimal conformal transformations. If I can show that it is Weyl tensor, I can also prove the statement. But do some alternatives exist?

Comment: Wikipedia has a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry#Under_a_conformal_change) which lists how different objects behave under conformal transformations.

Comment: You may work with infinitesimal transformations, like in this [paper](http://www.weylmann.com/conformal.pdf)